# Upload files to hosting servers

Tags: upload, file-upload

I want to ask how to upload file to some hosting server ( for example mediafire )?? I know that I must use something called POST/GET, but I don't know relly how to use them :/
I programming in Java,C++,C#,PHP so if you want write some small piece of code in these languages.

Comment: Are you trying to get your files onto the hosting server, or are you trying to allow your users to upload files using your application?

Comment: I want to upload files from my hard disk to remonte server, for example images to imageshack.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "HTTP POST request" in the documentation of your relevant language.